# Can I have an array with different number of columns in each row?

Tags: c++, algorithm, multidimensional-array, data-structures, graph

I want to use an array for storing adjacency list for a graph. In which each node have a different number of nodes connected to it. So I just want to have an array of the following type:

```
Row 0: 1 5 3
Row 1: 0 2 3
Row 2: 1
Row 3: 0 1 5 4
Row 4: 3 5
Row 5: 0 1 3 4
```

Comment: An `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` would allow this...is there some reason you need an array?

Comment: You can use a linked list for an adjacency list.

Comment: Yes you can. Array of double pointers. Each index can be initialized to an array of variable length.

Comment: Personally, I encourage an hard work in the system's design part, to increase efficient and decrease unnecessary use in resources. In this case, I would recommend you to think of a way to do this job with a single array/vector. Good Luck, and remember: Hard times brings good thinking!

Comment: @KorelK -- If the 2D array had uniform column lengths, then a single dimension array or vector would work.  However if each row contains a different number of columns (as the OP's data seems to suggest), then the problem becomes much more difficult to implement using a single array, and probably more convoluted.  No need for this just for the sake of trying to be "efficient".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I didn't say it will be easy :) Personally, I don't have the answer right now, but it can be a good algorithmic exercise..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a *vector of vectors of `int`*, where in each row you can store a different number of elements(nodes).

Following is an example code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using Row = std::vector<int>;
    std::vector<Row> rowVec;
    rowVec.reserve(6); // reserve memory if you know the size beforehand.
    // emplace each row of elements to the vector of vectors
    rowVec.emplace_back(Row{ 1, 5, 3 }); 
    rowVec.emplace_back(Row{ 0, 2, 3 });
    rowVec.emplace_back(Row{ 1 });
    rowVec.emplace_back(Row{ 0, 1, 5, 4 });
    rowVec.emplace_back(Row{ 3 ,5 });
    rowVec.emplace_back(Row{ 0, 1, 3, 4 });

    // to iterate throw the vector of vectors
    for (const Row& row : rowVec)
    {
        for (const int element : row)
            std::cout << element << " ";
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
1 5 3 
0 2 3 
1 
0 1 5 4 
3 5 
0 1 3 4
```

Comment: May be also give the same example using `char **` to show explicitly to the OP in that case it is needed to malloc (then free) the vectors and also to memorize the length else these vectors cannot be used ?

Comment: @bruno I think that should be the second option a C++ programmer should have selected, as long as `std::vector` solves the problem.(IMHO) BTW, that could be just another answer.

Comment: I said that to allow the OP to compare the right/simple way you did and the complicated one using arrays, because the OP question is "how to do with array" and your answer is "look how to do with std::vector", so _in fine_ you do not answer to the OP question, and I think it is better to say more to explain why with the code using arrays ;-)

Answer (score 2):

What you want is partially achievable using the `new` keyword but not exactly how you think. For a 3D array, all the elements must have the first dimension of the same size. Further, each 2D array within it must have the same row dimension. 
A 3D array is nothing but an array of arrays of arrays or more like an array of matrices.
Let our 3D array be A
It may look like:

```
A = [[[y1_x1,y1_x2],[y2_x1,y2_x2]],[[y3_x1,y3_x2,],[y4_x1,y4_x2]]]
```

That's two elements `A[0]` and `A[1]`
Within each, there are two other elements `A[0][0], A[0][1]`and `A[1][0], A[1][1]`
Those four elements have other two elements in it :

```
A[0][0][0]// which is y1_x1
A[0][0][1]// which is y1_x2

A[1][1][0]// which is y2_x1
A[1][1][1]// which is y2_x2

A[1][0][0]// which is y3_x1
A[1][0][1]// which is y3_x2

A[1][1][0]// which is y4_x1
A[1][1][1]// which is y4_x2
```

Now imagine, one of the elements from A[0] and A[1] could be a matrix and the other simply one value like:

```
A = [[[y1_x1,y1_x2],[y2_x1,y2_x1]],y3]
```

There are 4 ways to refer to A[0] and only 1 way to refer to A[1]
This can also be the case in the second dimension:

```
A = [[[y1_x1,y1_x2],],y2], y3]
```

There are two ways to refer to A[0][0] but only 1 for A[0][1].

You can create an array of array of pointers each of those pointers referring to an array.

```
int ***z;
z = new int**[z-size];
z[0] = new int*[y-size];
z[1] = new int*[y-size];
...
z[0][0] = new int[x-size];
z[0][1] = new int[x-size]
```

This process, of course, can be simplified using a `for` loop if sizes are same